# model.matrix() with na.action=NULL?

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a formula and a data frame, and I want to extract the `model.matrix()`. However, I need the resulting matrix to include the NAs that were found in the original dataset. If I were to use `model.frame()` to do this, I would simply pass it `na.action=NULL`. However, the output I need is of the `model.matrix()` format. Specifically, I need only the right-hand side variables, I need the output to be a matrix (not a data frame), and I need factors to be converted to a series of dummy variables.

I'm sure I could hack something together using loops or something, but I was wondering if anyone could suggest a cleaner and more efficient workaround. Thanks a lot for your time!

And here's an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20),5,4), gl(5,2))
dat[3,5] <- NA
names(dat) <- c(letters[1:4], 'fact')
ff <- a ~ b + fact

# This omits the row with a missing observation on the factor
model.matrix(ff, dat) 

# This keeps the NA, but it gives me a data frame and does not dichotomize the factor
model.frame(ff, dat, na.action=NULL)
```

Here is what I would like to obtain:

```
   (Intercept)          b fact2 fact3 fact4 fact5
1            1  0.7266086     0     0     0     0
2            1 -0.6088697     0     0     0     0
3            NA 0.4643360     NA    NA    NA    NA
4            1 -1.1666248     1     0     0     0
5            1 -0.7577394     0     1     0     0
6            1  0.7266086     0     1     0     0
7            1 -0.6088697     0     0     1     0
8            1  0.4643360     0     0     1     0
9            1 -1.1666248     0     0     0     1
10           1 -0.7577394     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can mess around a little with the `model.matrix` object, based on the rownames :

```
MM <- model.matrix(ff,dat)
MM <- MM[match(rownames(dat),rownames(MM)),]
MM[,"b"] <- dat$b
rownames(MM) <- rownames(dat)
```

which gives :

```
> MM
     (Intercept)         b fact2 fact3 fact4 fact5
1              1 0.9583010     0     0     0     0
2              1 0.3266986     0     0     0     0
3             NA 1.4992358    NA    NA    NA    NA
4              1 1.2867461     1     0     0     0
5              1 0.5024700     0     1     0     0
6              1 0.9583010     0     1     0     0
7              1 0.3266986     0     0     1     0
8              1 1.4992358     0     0     1     0
9              1 1.2867461     0     0     0     1
10             1 0.5024700     0     0     0     1
```

Alternatively, you can use `contrasts()` to do the work for you. Constructing the matrix by hand would be :

```
cont <- contrasts(dat$fact)[as.numeric(dat$fact),]
colnames(cont) <- paste("fact",colnames(cont),sep="")
out <- cbind(1,dat$b,cont)
out[is.na(dat$fact),1] <- NA
colnames(out)[1:2]<- c("Intercept","b")
rownames(out) <- rownames(dat)
```

which gives :

```
> out
     Intercept          b fact2 fact3 fact4 fact5
1            1  0.2534288     0     0     0     0
2            1  0.2697760     0     0     0     0
3           NA -0.8236879    NA    NA    NA    NA
4            1 -0.6053445     1     0     0     0
5            1  0.4608907     0     1     0     0
6            1  0.2534288     0     1     0     0
7            1  0.2697760     0     0     1     0
8            1 -0.8236879     0     0     1     0
9            1 -0.6053445     0     0     0     1
10           1  0.4608907     0     0     0     1
```

In any case, both methods can be incorporated in a function that can deal with more complex formulae. I leave the exercise to the reader (what do I loath that sentence when I meet it in a paper ;-) )

Comment: "I leave the exercise to the reader" - but it's perfect for lecture notes ;)

Comment: `match` call is brilliant, that's what I was missing!

Comment: match() works beautifully. Incidentally, this solved another problem I had been struggling with for a bit. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 55):

Joris's suggestion works, but a quicker and cleaner way to do this is via the global na.action setting. **The 'Pass' option achieves our goal of preserving NA's from the original dataset.**

### Option 1: Pass

Resulting matrix will contain NA's in rows corresponding to the original dataset.

```
options(na.action='na.pass')
model.matrix(ff, dat)
```

### Option 2: Omit

Resulting matrix will skip rows containing NA's.

```
options(na.action='na.omit')
model.matrix(ff, dat)
```

### Option 3: Fail

An error will occur if the original data contains NA's.

```
options(na.action='na.fail')
model.matrix(ff, dat)
```

Of course, always be careful when changing global options because they can alter behavior of other parts of your code. A cautious person might store the original setting with something like `current.na.action <- options('na.action')`, and then change it back after making the model.matrix.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: To be clear, one way to reset the `options('na.action')` to its original state is: `current.na.action <- options('na.action'`, then `options('na.action' = current.na.action$na.action)`. Note that not using the name 'na.action' to extract the string variable from `current.na.action` can lead to infinite recursion and "Protection stack overflow" errors, especially if you are using the construct within a function with `on.exit`.

Answer (score 43):

Another way is to use the `model.frame` function with argument `na.action=na.pass` as your second argument to `model.matrix`:

```
> model.matrix(ff, model.frame(~ ., dat, na.action=na.pass))
   (Intercept)          b fact2 fact3 fact4 fact5
1            1 -1.3560754     0     0     0     0
2            1  2.5476965     0     0     0     0
3            1  0.4635628    NA    NA    NA    NA
4            1 -0.2871379     1     0     0     0
5            1  2.2684958     0     1     0     0
6            1 -1.3560754     0     1     0     0
7            1  2.5476965     0     0     1     0
8            1  0.4635628     0     0     1     0
9            1 -0.2871379     0     0     0     1
10           1  2.2684958     0     0     0     1
```

`model.frame` allows you to set the appropriate action for `na.action` which is maintained when `model.matrix` is called.

Comment: Thanks, but the first paragraph of my question explains why this doesn't work in the application I had in mind.

Comment: @Vincent, the `model.frame` is just an argument to `model.matrix` so the output is the format of `model.matrix`. Isn't the output I've shown what you want?

Comment: wow! I really need to work on my reading skills. This is a really cool solution; didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: This answer seems to be the way to go; hopefully people find it even though older answers rated higher

Comment: Preferred solution for not messing with global options

Answer (score 25):

I half-stumbled across a simpler solution after looking at [mattdevlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4346952/mattdevlin) and [Nathan Gould](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147440/nathan-gould)'s answers:

```
 model.matrix.lm(ff, dat, na.action = "na.pass")
```

`model.matrix.default` may not support the `na.action` argument, but `model.matrix.lm` does!

(I found `model.matrix.lm` from Rstudio's auto-complete suggestions — it appears to be the only non-default method for `model.matrix` if you haven't loaded any libraries that add others. Then I just guessed it might support the `na.action` argument.)

Comment: Thanks @onestop, I think this should be the recommended answer.

Comment: this should be the recommended answer!

Comment: This worked the best. model.matrix doesn't seem to respect the na.action.