# sparse.model.matrix loses rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am working on regular `data.frame` that looks to be to big for `glm` function so I've decided I'll work on a sparse represantation of a model matrix so I could put this sparse matrix into `glmnet` function. But `sparse.model.matrix` looks like to drops some rows from original matrix. Any idea why that happens and any solution how to avoid that?
Code below:

```
> mm <- sparse.model.matrix(~clicks01+kl_tomek*bc1+hours+plec+1, 
data = daneOst)
> dim(mm)
[1] 1253223     292
> dim(daneOst)
[1] 1258836       6
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've had some success with changing the `na.action` to `na.pass`, this includes all the rows in my matrix:

```
options(na.action='na.pass')
```

Just note that this is a global option, so you probably want to set it back to it original value after, to not mess with the rest of your code.

```
previous_na_action <- options('na.action')
options(na.action='na.pass')
# Do your stuff...

options(na.action=previous_na_action$na.action)
```

Solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19544588/209882) answer.

Comment: Note that I'm using this for tree-based models that can deal with NA values. YMMV

Comment: I think this is the best solution, so far. That's why I am accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

It's due to the NA's !

Run `sum(complete.cases(mm))`. I bet it also gives you 1253223.

So replace the NA's in your dataframe by a value (eg. 'IMPUTED_NA' or -99999), and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

`@WillemM` is correct. The presence of `NAs` will trip off sparse matrix. With big data sets, the best approach is to read in your file into a data frame with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and then choose whatever imputation method you want. If you choose to use a tree based learning methods, its easier to impute these `NAs` with something not present in the data set. Multiple imputation on big data sets will take insanely long, and you may also lose R sessions.