# Why these two formulas give two different correlograms?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to compute a correlation matrix for a dataframe (named "df") that contains both numeric variables, and boolean variables (true, false) and has some missing values.

DF is like

```
df <- data.frame(
idcode = c(1:10),
contract = c ("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", NA, NA, "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"FALSE", "TRUE"),
score = c (1.17, 5, 7.2, 6.6, 3, 3.8, 7.2, 9.1, 5.4, 2.21),
CEO = c("FALSE", 
NA,"TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE"))
```

I have found two similar alternatives to compute this, but they give me different results:

```
data.matrix(df) %>% cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs") %>% round(digit=3)
```

and

```
model.matrix(~0+., data=df) %>% cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs") %>% round(digit=3)
```

Could someone please explain me why the two correlation matrixes differ, and what is the correct method to use to compute the correlation matrix in this case?

For example, why does the correlation for the pair CEO-Score differ?

Comment: Your edits improve the question, but we can't run your code:  we don't have `df`.  Could you include code to produce `df`, and show the differences in the resulting matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions `model.matrix` and `data.matrix` behave differently in several ways, including what happens if there are `NA` values, and how non-numeric variables are handled. See the help pages.

By default, entire rows are deleted in the presence of `NA` when using `model.matrix`. In `data.matrix`, these are kept and contribute to `cor(use = "pairwise.complete.obs")` observations, if not the entire rows are `NA`. This explains the different correlation coefficients.

If you have to use `model.matrix`, you could set the option to pass `NA` values (see solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616210/model-matrix-with-na-action-null)) and handle `NA` values in `cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs")`.

**Get data**

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  idcode = c(1:10),
  contract = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
  score = c (1.17, 5, 7.2, 6.6, 3, 3.8, 7.2, 9.1, 5.4, 2.21),
  CEO = c(FALSE,NA,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Note that logical variables should be coded without "", but the results will look the same here.

**Default behaviour of model.matrix**

If there are `NA` values, `model.matrix` drops the entire row while `data.matrix` keeps them. This is due to the default `options()$na.action`, which is set to `na.omit` and which only affecs `model.matrix`.

```r
options()$na.action
#[1] "na.omit"

model.matrix(~0 + ., data = df)
#>    idcode contractFALSE contractTRUE score CEOTRUE
#> 1       1             0            1  1.17       0
#> 3       3             1            0  7.20       1
#> 4       4             1            0  6.60       1
#> 7       7             0            1  7.20       1
#> 8       8             0            1  9.10       1
#> 9       9             1            0  5.40       1
#> 10     10             0            1  2.21       1
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 1 2 2 3 4
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$contract
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
#> 
#> attr(,"contrasts")$CEO
#> [1] "contr.treatment"

data.matrix(df)
#>       idcode contract score CEO
#>  [1,]      1        2  1.17   1
#>  [2,]      2        1  5.00  NA
#>  [3,]      3        1  7.20   2
#>  [4,]      4        1  6.60   2
#>  [5,]      5       NA  3.00   2
#>  [6,]      6       NA  3.80   2
#>  [7,]      7        2  7.20   2
#>  [8,]      8        2  9.10   2
#>  [9,]      9        1  5.40   2
#> [10,]     10        2  2.21   2
```

**Behaviour with na.action = "na.pass"**

```r
# set na.action options
oldpar <- options()$na.action
options(na.action ="na.pass")

model.matrix(~0 + ., data = df)
#>    idcode contractFALSE contractTRUE score CEOTRUE
#> 1       1             0            1  1.17       0
#> 2       2             1            0  5.00      NA
#> 3       3             1            0  7.20       1
#> 4       4             1            0  6.60       1
#> 5       5            NA           NA  3.00       1
#> 6       6            NA           NA  3.80       1
#> 7       7             0            1  7.20       1
#> 8       8             0            1  9.10       1
#> 9       9             1            0  5.40       1
#> 10     10             0            1  2.21       1
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 1 2 2 3 4
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$contract
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
#> 
#> attr(,"contrasts")$CEO
#> [1] "contr.treatment"

data.matrix(df)
#>       idcode contract score CEO
#>  [1,]      1        2  1.17   1
#>  [2,]      2        1  5.00  NA
#>  [3,]      3        1  7.20   2
#>  [4,]      4        1  6.60   2
#>  [5,]      5       NA  3.00   2
#>  [6,]      6       NA  3.80   2
#>  [7,]      7        2  7.20   2
#>  [8,]      8        2  9.10   2
#>  [9,]      9        1  5.40   2
#> [10,]     10        2  2.21   2
```

**Compare correlation coefficients**

```r
data.matrix(df) %>% cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs") %>% round(digit=3)
#>          idcode contract  score    CEO
#> idcode    1.000    0.312  0.177  0.625
#> contract  0.312    1.000 -0.226 -0.354
#> score     0.177   -0.226  1.000  0.548
#> CEO       0.625   -0.354  0.548  1.000

model.matrix(~0+., data=df) %>% cor(use="pairwise.complete.obs") %>% round(digit=3)
#>               idcode contractFALSE contractTRUE  score CEOTRUE
#> idcode         1.000        -0.312        0.312  0.177   0.625
#> contractFALSE -0.312         1.000       -1.000  0.226   0.354
#> contractTRUE   0.312        -1.000        1.000 -0.226  -0.354
#> score          0.177         0.226       -0.226  1.000   0.548
#> CEOTRUE        0.625         0.354       -0.354  0.548   1.000
```

Note that the two functions handle logical variables data differently (`model.matrix` creates two dummy variables for *contract*, and one dummy variable for *CEO* (see discussion in the comments section to this Answer), `data.matrix` creates a single binary integer variable), which is reflected in the correlation matrix.

**reset default options**

```r
options(na.action = oldpar)
```

**Session Info**

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] knitr_1.33      magrittr_2.0.1  rlang_0.4.11    fastmap_1.1.0  
#>  [5] fansi_0.5.0     stringr_1.4.0   styler_1.5.1    highr_0.9      
#>  [9] tools_4.1.1     xfun_0.25       utf8_1.2.2      withr_2.4.2    
#> [13] htmltools_0.5.2 ellipsis_0.3.2  yaml_2.2.1      digest_0.6.27  
#> [17] tibble_3.1.4    lifecycle_1.0.0 crayon_1.4.1    purrr_0.3.4    
#> [21] vctrs_0.3.8     fs_1.5.0        glue_1.4.2      evaluate_0.14  
#> [25] rmarkdown_2.10  reprex_2.0.1    stringi_1.7.4   compiler_4.1.1 
#> [29] pillar_1.6.2    backports_1.2.1 pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You are considering the columns as characcter rather than loigical. That should make the two have the same results

Comment: Hi and thanks! I just changed them to logicals, but the two functions still treat them differently (model.matrix creates two dummy variables from one logical variable, while data.matrix treats a logical as a binary).

Comment: checkk again. when you have a logical variable, it is already 0, 1 so no two dummy variables will be created. for example why do you have CEO TRUE but not CEO FALSE  yet you have both contract TRUE and contract FALSE columns?

Comment: Hi Onyambu. I see now why it's weird, one logical (contract) gives two dummy variables while the other (CEO) doesn't. But I checked again, with the same results (it's a reprex example after all). I don't know why this happens, any idea? Maybe you could check it again?